# How to prevent repeating the same code in cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift

Can you please help me to find a solution and not to copy the same code again and again? Now I do have this code

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productImageCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductImageCell
        if let product = self.product {
            cell.product = product
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productDetailCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductDetailCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        if let product = self.product {
            cell.product = product
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productDeliveryCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductDeliveryTimeCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productDeliveryCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductDeliveryTimeCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can see I do copy this part again and again

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productImageCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductImageCell
    if let product = self.product {
        cell.product = product
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
```

I did try something like that but it is not working

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productImageCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductImageCell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productDetailCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductDetailCell
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productDeliveryCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductDeliveryTimeCell
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productDeliveryCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductDeliveryTimeCell
    }

    if let product = self.product {
        cell.product = product
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include `product` property in all cells. Remove `indexpath.row == 2`  block, it does nothing.

write code like this ,

```
if indexPath.row == 1 {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productImageCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductImageCell
    cell.product == "" //clear product field for reusing property 
     if let product = self.product {
        cell.product = product
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
} else if .....
```

Answer (score 0):

> //You need to use same class in multiple cell as like,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:HomeCell!

    if homeArray[indexPath.row]["type"] == "1" {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductTitleCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
    }
    else if homeArray[indexPath.row]["type"] == "2" {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductImageCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
    }

    cell.lbl_Title_1.text = homeArray[indexPath.row]["product_name"]
    if cell.tag == 2 {
        cell.imageview_1.image = UIImage(named: homeArray[indexPath.row]["product_image"]!)
    }

    return cell
}
```

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: In this case, I am not able to cast any other cells to it cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: productDetailCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductDetailCell